# Output AWS cli sync command from bat file to log file with timestamp

Tags: batch-file, amazon-s3, logging, command-line-interface

I would like to run aws s3 sync on a scheduled bat file, logging the output to a file with timestamps.  Here is the bat file:

```
cls
set ARG1=%1
if %ARG1%==test color 3d
if %ARG1%==prod color 4f
echo %DATE% %TIME%
aws s3 sync s3://bucket1/ s3://bucket2/ --no-progress --profile account.%ARG1% >> c:\temp\AWS\%ARG1%\log.txt 2>> c:\temp\AWS\%ARG1%\error_log.txt
TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
exit 0
```

How do I add %DATE% and %TIME% to the output?

Comment: echo %DATE% %TIME%>> c:\temp\AWS\%ARG1%\log.txt

Comment: You should also look into [S3 Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html)